# apache beam trigger when all necessary files in gcs bucket is uploaded

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I'm new to beam so the whole triggering stuff really confuse me.
I have files that are uploaded regularly to gcs to a path that looks something like this: `node-<num>/<table_name>/<timestamp>/files_parts`
and I need to write something that would trigger when all 8 parts of a file exist.

Their names are something like that: `file_1_part_1, file_1_part_2, file_2_part_1, file_2_part_2`
(there could be multiple files parts in the same dir but if its a problem I could ask for it to change).

Is there any way to create this trigger? and if not what do you suggest I could do instead?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the Java SDK, you can use a transform [Watch](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.29.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/Watch.html) to achieve this. I don't see a counterpart in the Python SDK though.

I think it's better to write a program polling the files in the GCS directory. When 8 parts of a file is available, [publish](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/quickstart-client-libraries#publish_messages) a message containing the file name to [Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub) or similar product.

Then in your Beam pipeline, use the Pub/Sub topic as the [streaming](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/python-streaming/) source to do your ETL.